# MySQL rank function with duplicates

Tags: mysql, rank

I'm trying to get a ranking of a query each time I run it but can't seem to get it right.
Also, I want to be able to display the same rank rows as the same number. i.e. 1,2,2,4,5,5,5,8.

I have had a stab at the query but I'm only able to get the ranking based on the original order of the records in the table and not by the sort that my query is performing.

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

```
SET @rank:=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
     , masters_2014.name
     , masters_2014.player1
     , player1_score.hole as player1_thru
     , player1_score.to_par_s as player1_to_par
     , masters_2014.player2
     , player2_score.hole as player2_thru
     , player2_score.to_par_s as player2_to_par
     , masters_2014.player3
     , player3_score.hole as player3_thru
     , player3_score.to_par_s as player3_to_par 
     , (player1_score.`to_par` + player2_score.`to_par` + player3_score.`to_par`) as team_total
  FROM masters_2014
INNER 
  JOIN leaderboard_A as player1_score 
    ON player1_score.name = masters_2014.player1
   AND player1_score.tournament_name = 'masters tournament' 
   AND player1_score.year = 2014
INNER
  JOIN leaderboard_A as player2_score 
    ON player2_score.name = masters_2014.player2
   AND player2_score.tournament_name = 'masters tournament' 
   AND player2_score.year = 2014
INNER
  JOIN leaderboard_A as player3_score 
    ON player3_score.name = masters_2014.player3
   AND player3_score.tournament_name = 'masters tournament' 
   AND player3_score.year = 2014
ORDER BY team_total

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderboard_A` (
  `league` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `cut` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `wd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `tie` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pos` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `pos_s` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `to_par` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
  `to_par_s` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hole` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `round` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `round_s` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `round_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `round_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `round_3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `round_4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `tournament_id` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tournament_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `year` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`league`,`id`,`tournament_id`),
  KEY `pos` (`pos`),
  KEY `player_key` (`name`,`tournament_name`,`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `leaderboard_A`
--



   INSERT INTO `leaderboard_A` (`name`, `to_par`, `to_par_s`, `tournament_name`, `year`) VALUES
('Couples, Fred', 2, '2', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Langer, Bernhard', 0, 'Par', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Lyle, Sandy', 9, '9', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Mize, Larry', 16, '16', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Olazabal, Jose Maria', 6, '6', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Stricker, Steve', 5, '5', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Singh, Vijay', 7, '7', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Weir, Mike', 9, '9', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Furyk, Jim', 1, '1', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Bjorn, Thomas', 0, 'Par', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Clarke, Darren', 9, '9', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Jimenez, Miguel Angel', -4, '-4', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Cink, Stewart', 1, '1', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Gallacher, Stephen', 6, '6', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Westwood, Lee', -1, '-1', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Senden, John', 0, 'Par', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Stenson, Henrik', 1, '1', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Rose, Justin', 1, '1', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Kuchar, Matt', -2, '-2', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('de Jonge, Brendon', 7, '7', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Poulter, Ian', 2, '2', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Choi, K.J.', 6, '6', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Scott, Adam', 1, '1', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Jaidee, Thongchai', 7, '7', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Mahan, Hunter', 4, '4', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Haas, Bill', 2, '2', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Fernandez-Castano, Gonzalo', 4, '4', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Molinari, Francesco', 11, '11', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Bowditch, Steven', 4, '4', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Donaldson, Jamie', 1, '1', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Walker, Jimmy', 0, 'Par', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Watson, Bubba', -8, '-8', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Glover, Lucas', 8, '8', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Oosthuizen, Louis', 3, '3', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Stadler, Kevin', 0, 'Par', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Watney, Nick', 9, '9', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Streelman, Kevin', 8, '8', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Kaymer, Martin', 5, '5', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Snedeker, Brandt', 7, '7', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Blixt, Jonas', -5, '-5', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Day, Jason', 2, '2', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('McIlroy, Rory', 0, 'Par', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Luiten, Joost', 4, '4', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Horschel, Billy', 7, '7', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Kirk, Chris', 1, '1', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Woodland, Gary', 4, '4', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Fowler, Rickie', -2, '-2', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Olesen, Thorbjorn', 9, '9', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Spieth, Jordan', -5, '-5', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Henley, Russell', 5, '5', 'Masters Tournament', 2014),
('Goss, Oliver', 10, '10', 'Masters Tournament', 2014);
CREATE TABLE `masters_2014` (
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `player1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `player2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `player3` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `player1_key` (`player1`),
  KEY `player2_key` (`player2`),
  KEY `player3_key` (`player3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `masters_2014`
--

INSERT INTO `masters_2014` (`name`, `player1`, `player2`, `player3`) VALUES
('Team 1', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Henley, Russell', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 10', 'Gallacher, Stephen', 'Scott, Adam', 'Spieth, Jordan'),
('Team 11', 'Luiten, Joost', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 12', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 13', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 14', 'Furyk, Jim', 'Kaymer, Martin', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 15', 'Day, Jason', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'Streelman, Kevin'),
('Team 16', 'Choi, K.J.', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Poulter, Ian'),
('Team 17', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 18', 'Day, Jason', 'Luiten, Joost', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 19', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'Molinari, Francesco', 'Stricker, Steve'),
('Team 2', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Stenson, Henrik'),
('Team 20', 'Furyk, Jim', 'Horschel, Billy', 'Kuchar, Matt'),
('Team 21', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 22', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'Senden, John', 'Westwood, Lee'),
('Team 23', 'Couples, Fred', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 24', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 25', 'Kaymer, Martin', 'Rose, Justin', 'Westwood, Lee'),
('Team 26', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Rose, Justin', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 27', 'Westwood, Lee', 'Watson, Bubba', 'Couples, Fred'),
('Team 28', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Kuchar, Matt'),
('Team 29', 'Choi, K.J.', 'Oosthuizen, Louis', 'Poulter, Ian'),
('Team 3', 'Choi, K.J.', 'Day, Jason', 'Donaldson, Jamie'),
('Team 30', 'Day, Jason', 'Gallacher, Stephen', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 31', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 32', 'Couples, Fred', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Woodland, Gary'),
('Team 33', 'Day, Jason', 'Fernandez-Castano, Gonzalo', 'Westwood, Lee'),
('Team 34', 'Day, Jason', 'Senden, John', 'Spieth, Jordan'),
('Team 35', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Horschel, Billy', 'Westwood, Lee'),
('Team 36', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Snedeker, Brandt', 'Stenson, Henrik'),
('Team 37', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Singh, Vijay', 'Watson, Bubba'),
('Team 38', 'Fernandez-Castano, Gonzalo', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Westwood, Lee'),
('Team 39', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 4', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Haas, Bill', 'Woodland, Gary'),
('Team 40', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 41', 'Bjorn, Thomas', 'Snedeker, Brandt', 'Watson, Bubba'),
('Team 42', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Scott, Adam', 'Watson, Bubba'),
('Team 43', 'Donaldson, Jamie', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Spieth, Jordan'),
('Team 44', 'Couples, Fred', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 45', 'Olesen, Thorbjorn', 'Oosthuizen, Louis', 'Stricker, Steve'),
('Team 46', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 47', 'Couples, Fred', 'Donaldson, Jamie', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 48', 'Bjorn, Thomas', 'Day, Jason', 'Walker, Jimmy'),
('Team 49', 'Day, Jason', 'Scott, Adam', 'Stadler, Kevin'),
('Team 5', 'Couples, Fred', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Kuchar, Matt'),
('Team 50', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 51', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 52', 'Day, Jason', 'Scott, Adam', 'Stadler, Kevin'),
('Team 53', 'Day, Jason', 'Haas, Bill', 'Molinari, Francesco'),
('Team 54', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Walker, Jimmy'),
('Team 55', 'Kaymer, Martin', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Stricker, Steve'),
('Team 56', 'Horschel, Billy', 'Rose, Justin', 'Westwood, Lee'),
('Team 57', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 58', 'Kaymer, Martin', 'Oosthuizen, Louis', 'Rose, Justin'),
('Team 59', 'De Jonge, Brendon', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 6', 'Bjorn, Thomas', 'Scott, Adam', 'Westwood, Lee'),
('Team 60', 'Cink, Stewart', 'Snedeker, Brandt', 'Watson, Bubba'),
('Team 61', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Furyk, Jim', 'Watney, Nick'),
('Team 62', 'Henley, Russell', 'Scott, Adam', 'Spieth, Jordan'),
('Team 63', 'Day, Jason', 'Luiten, Joost', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 64', 'Kaymer, Martin', 'Poulter, Ian', 'Rose, Justin'),
('Team 65', 'Couples, Fred', 'Furyk, Jim', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 66', 'Donaldson, Jamie', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Spieth, Jordan'),
('Team 67', 'Cink, Stewart', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Walker, Jimmy'),
('Team 68', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'Langer, Bernhard', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 69', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 7', 'Day, Jason', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'Stadler, Kevin'),
('Team 70', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 71', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 72', 'Furyk, Jim', 'Kaymer, Martin', 'Stenson, Henrik'),
('Team 73', 'Bjorn, Thomas', 'Scott, Adam', 'Spieth, Jordan'),
('Team 74', 'Gallacher, Stephen', 'Rose, Justin', 'Scott, Adam'),
('Team 75', 'Choi, K.J.', 'Snedeker, Brandt', 'Stricker, Steve'),
('Team 76', 'Day, Jason', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 77', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Scott, Adam', 'Stadler, Kevin'),
('Team 78', 'Fowler, Rickie', 'Kaymer, Martin', 'McIlroy, Rory'),
('Team 79', 'Fernandez-Castano, Gonzalo', 'Rose, Justin', 'Watson, Bubba'),
('Team 8', 'Kuchar, Matt', 'Senden, John', 'Walker, Jimmy'),
('Team 9', 'Jimenez, Miguel Angel', 'McIlroy, Rory', 'Scott, Adam');
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be anything to do with PHP or excel, just MySQL. You should only tag the relevant technologies, even if you may be using the other technologies elsewhere in the project.

Comment: Sorry George I have updated the tags now.

Comment: No worries, you're new here. I have been pulled up for it in the past myself. :)

Comment: can you post some sample data? not going to be easy to answer without being able to see what were working with and why you want your rank in the order you posted

Comment: My data is big enough is there anywhere I can post it to test it online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your question `How difficult is it also to have "T" before any ties?`... its not difficult, but I can't do it on my end because I dont have any data for ties..

---

(1. if you want to edit the table to add "T")

`UPDATE leaderboard_A SET tie = Concat('T', tie);`

---

(2. if you want to add "T" to the ties without changing it in the database)

```
    SELECT
         CONCAT('T', tie) AS ties,
         masters_2014.name
       , masters_2014.player1
       , player1_score.to_par_s AS player1_to_par
       , masters_2014.player2
       , player2_score.to_par_s AS player2_to_par
       , masters_2014.player3
       , player3_score.to_par_s AS player3_to_par
       , (player1_score.`to_par` + player2_score.`to_par` + player3_score.`to_par`) AS team_total
    FROM masters_2014
```

---

(3. if you mean add "T" to the rank) see [THIS_FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2df86/29)

all you have to do is the concat in the `IF` like this

`IF (counter = 1, @rank:= placeholder, CONCAT("T ", @rank)) AS ranker`

---

FOR YOUR ANSWER
see new [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2df86/28) for final result ---

what I had to do was get a place holder that counted +1 for each row.. then put that in for every time you have a different score while setting @rank equal to it.. or else just put in @rank because it is equal to the placeholder's first value for that score. I was getting some wonky results at first because the placeholder @c was getting set to the number of rows returned (55) +1 for each row... instead of starting at 0 it was starting at 55... Im thinking this is just a bug with sqlfiddle as it shouldn't be doing that... so let me know if its doing that in your environment. here is the SQL:

```
SET @rank :=0, @a :=0, @b :=0, @c :=0;

SELECT
  name,
  player1,
  player1_to_par,
  player2,
  player2_to_par,
  player3,
  player3_to_par,
  team_total,
  IF (counter = 1, @rank:= placeholder, @rank) AS ranker
FROM(
  SELECT
    *,
    @c := @c +1 AS placeholder,
    IF(@a <> team_total, @b := @b := 1, @b :=0) AS counter,
    @a := team_total
  from(
    SELECT
         masters_2014.name
       , masters_2014.player1
       , player1_score.to_par_s AS player1_to_par
       , masters_2014.player2
       , player2_score.to_par_s AS player2_to_par
       , masters_2014.player3
       , player3_score.to_par_s AS player3_to_par
       , (player1_score.`to_par` + player2_score.`to_par` + player3_score.`to_par`) AS team_total
    FROM masters_2014
    INNER JOIN leaderboard_A AS player1_score
      ON player1_score.name = masters_2014.player1
      AND player1_score.tournament_name = 'masters tournament'
      AND player1_score.year = 2014
    INNER JOIN leaderboard_A AS player2_score
      ON player2_score.name = masters_2014.player2
      AND player2_score.tournament_name = 'masters tournament'
      AND player2_score.year = 2014
    INNER JOIN leaderboard_A AS player3_score
      ON player3_score.name = masters_2014.player3
      AND player3_score.tournament_name = 'masters tournament'
      AND player3_score.year = 2014
    ORDER BY team_total
  )AS t
)AS FINAL
```

Comment: That's exactly the idea I want, so I am supposed to create the data then rank the results. Any good pointers to get the rankings like this. i.e. 1,2,2,4,5,5,5,8?

Comment: I need data to work with... and I can recreate it and do it for you.. but without data im flying blind so I don't know if it will solve what you specifically want. -- edit your question with a section of what the data looks like

Comment: Thanks John, I've added in some data above hopefully it's enough to see what's going on.

Comment: almost there... I can't do the join's because there is no year, tournament_name, or hole in the data you provided

Comment: Sorry about that, how's that now? They're all the same anyway if you want to populate the fields. I just extracted the data for that tournament.

Comment: ok i got it to repopulate... now you want the rank to count +1 for each different score right? so like the team_total is -11, -7, -6, -6, -6... so you want the rank to be 1, 2, 3, 3, 3?

Comment: Yeah exactly all the way thru the results. I could have a few hundred results though as this is a sample. How difficult is it also to have "T" before any ties? Thanks again.

Comment: ok just edited with the solution.. i'll add the fiddle as well

Comment: so you will have to add a few more columns.. for it to be the same as what you had.. the fiddle wouldn't build the schema without data for `hole`, `league`, `id`, etc.. so I just removed them from the schema to build it.. the math is there though so just add that to your part

Comment: It's nearly there, I'm getting the output as 1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5 as where I want 1,2,3,3,3,6,6,8. I completely missed that on your comment earlier. Apologies for that. Also, your fiddle won't load for me for some reason. I had to remove the comments for it to work on my local MySQL.

Comment: whats the reason for the ranking like that? like whats the driver for it? (i need to understand what the logic is so I can do the math part).. sql fiddle sometimes doesn't like to load.. usually I just refresh a few times and it loads... yea the comments I added just for you to understand whats going on, not needed.

Comment: The reason for that is that if some comes joint 2nd with 3 other people for example that would mean 4 of them split 2nd place and there would be no 3rd or 4th place in a competition. The next place would be 6th. i.e. 1,2,2,2,2,6... I'll try the fiddle again but I got it working in MySQL without the comments don't think it liked the --- only --. Cheers

Comment: ok, so this may be a little tricky.. let me see what I can do

Comment: ok just cleared my whole answer and added the final result. please read the whole thing... you may or may not get weird results.. also look at the new fiddle.

Comment: Looks great just I get all -55 values but if I make the line IF (counter = 1, @rank:= (placeholder), CONCAT("T", @rank)) AS ranker it seems to displayed properly. Is it possible also to have the T in front of all ties as the first 2 in this example would be a tie also?

Comment: yea sorry i forgot to take the -55 out.. sql fiddle was adding 55 for some reason.. let me see.. i think its possible.. but i'm not positive lol

Comment: Honestly... its not easy to do that... i cant think of a way to do it at the moment... i need to brainstorm for a bit... do you need there to be a "T" before the ties?

Comment: No worries, it's only a nice thing to have. I've been doing it in Excel the past while and trying to replicate it online. It's a nice to have but you've helped me so much it's brought my further than I could have thought. Cheers @John Ruddell

Comment: ok well thanks for accepting the answer! good luck with what you're working on!

Comment: one thing you can do if you want.. is keep the concat method in there and then after you get the data in another programming language check for a "T" .. if it exists add a T to the previous item.

Comment: Hi @john, looking for an update if you can help on the above statement. My database structure has changed and now my masters_2014 table for player1, player2 and player3 now holds an integer value (i.e. 123).  In another table called players I have a players.id and players.name.  The id field in players table references the player1, player2, player3 field in the masters_2014 table.  Finding it hard to work out how to sub it in to still make the query above work? Any suggestions? Thanks